# Eigenvalue repulsion for non-symmetric random matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra

It's [well known](https://www.americanscientist.org/article/the-spectrum-of-riemannium) that eigenvalues of random symmetric matrices repel, is there any such law formulated for random non-symmetric matrices?

For instance, consider eigenvalues of random matrices obtained by adding complex numbers sampled IID from disk in complex plane to the following matrix

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

[image]

There are almost no eigenvalues at 0, hence there's a kind of repulsion. This is in contrast to adding same kind of noise to 0 matrix, no such repulsion is observed

[image]

[Notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/nn-linear/forum-nonsymmetric-repulsion.nb)